# How to take index value of entire table

Tags: angularjs

Currently I am displaying 5 rows per page. But if take index of the table in first page It is taking the index 0 to 6 for the first page. In second page again it is taking from 0 to 6. I want to know the selected index of the whole table with including (all pagination) table row values. How to take index of all the table rows

```
$scope.SampleTable[index].Name; //it is taking particular page index only
```

I want Entire page index value using tr dir-paginate

Comment: Share some code to clarify, screenshots will be fine

Comment: if its 5 rows per page, index should be between 0 to 4 including, how are you getting 0 to 6?

Comment: by mistake i said 0 to 6. It is taking 0 to 4 only

Answer (score 0):

If you have a variable in your controller specifying the current page (e.g. `$scope.currentPage`), you could do something like this:

```
$scope.SampleTable[index + ($scope.currentPage * 5 - 5)].Name;
```

Comment: Not correct! According to this, If on page 3, selecting 3rd row would give 5 whereas there are 5 rows on each page and index should be 12(staring from 0)

Comment: @Sajal You are right, I totally missed that. I updated my answer.